# How to see whether a symbol has been matched or not?

Tags: python

I am making a code puzzle where the user will be provided with a list of ten words encrypted with symbols. They have to decide which letters are represented by which symbols. I have to make it in such a way that, if a certain symbol has already been replaced by the user, the same symbol cannot be replaced by another letter. How to do this?

```
print "Python Puzzle Model\n\n\n"
textfile = open('words.txt')
words = textfile.read()
print words
print '\n\n'
print 'Lets replace the given code' 
words =  words.replace('#','o')


words =  words.replace('!','k')
print words

print '\n'
#print 'Which letter would you like to replace?\n'
x = raw_input(" Which symbol would you like to replace ")
y = raw_input(" Which letter would you like to replace it with ")
print '\n'

words = words.replace(x,y)
print '\n'

print words
```

Comment: Store the replaced symbols in a list and check if new replacement attempt is on an already replaced symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this, unless I misunderstood your question:

```
textfile = open('a.txt')
replace_dict_list = []

replace_symbol =  raw_input(" Which symbol would you like to replace ")
replace_letter = raw_input(" Which letter would you like to replace it with ")

dict = {replace_symbol:replace_letter}

already_exists = False
for item in replace_dict_list:
    if replace_symbol in item:
        already_exists = True
    else:
        replace_dict_list.append(dict)

if not already_exists:
    print "running"
    words = words.replace(replace_symbol, replace_letter)
```